# Marketing Cloud - Failed Email Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I created a new Data Extension and inserted new contacts on it by importing data from a CSV file. All the data was imported correctly to the DE (300.000 contacts), but when I sent an email to that DE a significantly portion was cut off from the sending activity (140.000 contacts).

What could be causing that?

I´m pretty sure the email addresses are valid and the data uploaded is good.

Comment: Some questions: was the send classification Default Commercial? Do some of these email addresses already exist in All Subscribers? Where were the email addresses obtained from?

Comment: Hi Antonio! Yes, actually many of these email addresses already exists in All Subscribers.
These emails were obtained from my company's local database. 
I expected some amount of bad data and therefore a difference between the number of emails on the DE and the number of sents, but a small difference, no that much.

Comment: Hi @conradosetti, as you have mentioned there are email address which is already present, check the associated subscriber status if its un-subscribed then email will not be sent.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I always check is field data types

Do you have [1 and only 1 field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=User-is-not-receiving-emails-even-if-there-is-correct-email-address-in-the-Data-Extension&language=en_US) in the DE with data type 'EmailAddress'

Then you could have any of the following

1. [List detective](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_list_detective.htm&type=5)
2. Bounced / Held
3. [Auto-Suppression](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_auto_suppresion_lists.htm&type=5)
4. [Exclusion Script](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320456&type=1&mode=1)
5. [Raise Error](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/raiseerror.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Yes, I have only 1 field in the DE with the data type 'EmailAddress'.

From the options you gave, the most likely for me is number 2, since many of the contacts already existed in All Subscribers and was used in preview sends.